# Efficient way to union two list with list or None value

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x, list

I have two list that can be `list` or `None`. I want to get third list with result of unique unite this two list.

- If `first` list is **None** and `second` is **None** - `result` will be **None**
- If `first` is **None** and `second` is not **None** - `result` will be `second`
- If `second` is **None** and `first` is not **None** - `result` will be `first`
- If `second` is not **None** and `first` is not **None** - `result` will be `first + second`

I do this simple with if condition:

```
result = first if first else second
if result is not None:
    try:
        result = list(set(first + second))
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

I want to do this in better way. Maybe you know way to solve this by one or more string using `itertools` or something else.

Comment: Other than that, shortest (though, may be not efficient) is `set((first or []) + (second or []))`

Comment: Isn't the goal to find unique elements?

Comment: @myaut, i want to find nore efficient way, if it will be bigger, so ok, it is fine!

Comment: @synchronizer, yes, the goal is find efficient way to get unique list

Comment: What is the expected result for `[1, 2, 3]` and `[2, None, 6]`?

Comment: @pylang, `[1, 2, 3, None, 6]`, why do you ask this? I want to solve case when `[1, 2, 3]` and `None` for efficient way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A one-liner solution using [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) can be :

```
set(itertools.chain.from_iterable((first or [], second or [])))
```

EDIT:

I made some timings of different solutions, here is what I obtain (on my computer, using python3.6), for 10000 iterations for 2 lists of 10000 items :

- OP way : 7.34 s
- raw set way (comment from @myaut : `set((first or []) + (second or []))` ) : 5.95 s
- itertools way : 5.69 s

So itertools way is a little bit faster, the `chain` method is better than the `+` operator for list :).

Comment: Warning: `first or []` is a Python anti-pattern since any falsy value will evaluate to []. It is better to use `first if first is not None else []`. From the [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/): "Errors should never pass silently."

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd be straightforward: if a list is `None`, replace it with an empty list, then concatenate both:

```
def concat(l1, l2):
    if l1 is None and l2 is None:
        return None
    elif l1 is None:
        l1 = []
    elif l2 is None:
        l2 = []

    s = set(l1 + l2)

    return  s
```

Some results:

```
>>> concat(None, None) is None
True
>>> concat([1,2,3], None)
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> concat(None, [4,5])
set([4, 5])
>>> concat([1,2,3], [4,5])
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> concat([1,2,3], [])
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> concat([], [])
set([])
```

There are many ways to do it but to me it is the clear case where there is no need to cleverness.